# Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception

Tags: magento-1.9, exception, debug

I have two store views with store codes en and mx.  Store ids 1 & 2. This exception only happens if I save or update a product in english or spanish store  views. Saving in default store view gives no exception.  It seems to be coming from Magento core according the this stack trace.  How can I debug this of fix it?

```
Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:977
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(582): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException()
#1 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Abstract.php(124): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore('modules')
#2 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Status.php(112): Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract->getStore()
#3 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php(137): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status->assignProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 1, NULL)
#4 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(29): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item->assignProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#5 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(958): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->addInventoryData(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(945): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'addInventoryDat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(259): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#8 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(145): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#9 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(381): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterLoad()
#10 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(116): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->_afterLoad()
#11 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(41): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(39)
#12 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(171): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->_initProduct()
#13 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(278): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#14 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(200): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#15 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(116): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(189): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/xxxx/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Here's  App.php:977

```
public function getAnyStoreView()
{
    $store = $this->getDefaultStoreView();
    if ($store) {             <-------line 977
        return $store;
    }
    foreach ($this->getStores() as $store) {
        return $store;
    }
}
```

Here's lines 581, 582 , 583 in App.php:

```
    if (!$store->getCode()) {
        $this->throwStoreException();
    }
```

Here's 122, 123,124, 125 in Abstract.php:

```
public function getStore()
{
    return Mage::app()->getStore($this->getStoreId());
}
```

Comment: Have you any extensions installed? `Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore('modules')` seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, I finally narrowed it down to an extension, Ax_Zoom.xml.  It's paid extension so I'll check with the developers.